# Who is "Kola Adzaj" - an African Esperantist present at the 1937 World Congress in Warsaw, Poland?

Tags: culture, history

In a text written in Hebrew, it's author, Polish Jewish esperantist Icchak Kominkowski, speaks about a friend named "Kola Adzaj", from Africa, who visited Warsaw at the occasion of the 1937 World Esperanto Conress. It's difficult to guess the right spelling of the name... Any hint would be very welcome!

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe something to help start the search, there is this interesting and detailed report from the congress: http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno-plus?aid=e0f&datum=1937&page=57&size=45 . I couldn’t find any mention of anyone from Africa though.

Comment: "it's author" -> "its author" ("it's" is short for "it is"; "its" is a possessive pronoun).

Comment: Is this text available anywhere? Could you write the exact title of the publication? I read some Yiddish, but I'm willing to translate the article for myself through a translator. I only know Kominkowski from his diary about Sompolno during the war (actually I'm from a nearby town). I am even more surprised that he passed on such interesting information! Kola was described in a very racist short story by Jean Forge - it's available here: https://sezonoj.ru/2020/12/forge/ I am tremendously curious to know what happened to him later (the war etc.)

Answer (score 8):

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Ajayi

Kola Ajayi
Kola AJAYI [aĝaji], kristana antaŭnomo: Nathaniel (naskiĝis la 23-an de aprilo 1906 en Warri, Niĝerio, mortodato nekonata) estis joruba esperantisto.

Ajayi estis angla ŝtatano, aktoro, esperantista prelegisto. Li restadis longe en Usono.

Li esperantistiĝis en 1931 en Bydgoszcz (ĉe fratoj Fethke). Depost 1932 li prelegis en Esperanto pri Afriko antaŭ neesperantista publiko. Li havis

en Pollando 45 prelegojn en 22 urboj antaŭ 8100 personoj kaj radiokantadon,
en Ĉeĥoslovakio 33 prelegojn en 21 urboj antaŭ 12 400 personoj (aprilo-majo 1933), du radioprezentadojn,
en Jugoslavio ĉ. 25 prelegojn (junio-septembro 1933).
Jean Forge en sia satira novelaro La Verda Raketo dediĉis al Kola Ajayi rakonton Nia nigra filo, sed li traktas lin kiel grandan infanon.